# ui-router Main View is rendering thrice and no controller are registering

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I am trying to create a SPA using angular ui-router with MVC. I am facing three issues.
1.The controllers OfferController.js and OfferCustomizationController.js are not registering.
2.I am getting the errors ' No reference point given for path '.offer', No reference point given for path '.customizations'.
3. Main view is rendering thrice.

I have no clue what am i missing. Please help.

I have included the following files in my Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Links.Scripts.angular_min_js"></script>
<script src="@Links.Scripts.ProductCatalog.app_js"></script>
<script src="@Links.Scripts.ProductCatalog.service_js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

I have made two views. Offers And OfferCustomizations. And a main view. Following is my code for the main view:

```
<div class="inside-data-div" ng-app="ProductCatalog">
    @*<div ui-view></div>*@
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                <div id="form-container">

                    <div class="page-header text-center">
                        <h2>Create Offer</h2>

                        <!-- the links to our nested states using relative paths -->
                        <!-- add the active class if the state matches our ui-sref -->
                        <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
                            <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".offer"><span>1</span> Offer Details</a>
                            <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".customizations"><span>2</span> Offer Customizations</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- use ng-submit to catch the form submission and use our Angular function -->
                    <form id="signup-form" ng-submit="SaveForm()">

                        <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
                        <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
                    </form>

                </div>

                <!-- show our formData as it is being typed -->
                <pre>
        {{ formData }}
    </pre>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Following is my code of app js:

```
var productCatalogApp = angular.module('ProductCatalog', ['ui.router']);
productCatalogApp.value('appName', 'Product Catalog');

productCatalogApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('wizard', {
            url: '/wizard',
            templateUrl: 'WizardSubForm',
            controller: 'WizardMainController'
        })

        // nested states 
        // each of these sections will have their own view
        // url will be nested (/form/profile)
        .state('wizard.offer', {
            url: '/offer',
            templateUrl: 'OfferForm',
            controller: 'OfferCtrlr'
        })

        // url will be /form/interests
        .state('wizard.customizations', {
            url: '/customizations',
            templateUrl: 'OfferCustomizations',
            controller: 'CustomizationCtrlr'
        });


    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/wizard/offer');
});

productCatalogApp.controller('WizardMainController', function ($scope) {

    // we will store all of our form data in this object
    $scope.formData = {};

    // function to process the form
    $scope.SaveForm = function () {
        alert('awesome!');
        $scope.formData = { "Offer": $scope.offer, QuestionGroups: $scope.QuestionGroups }
    };

});
```

This is how i'm registering my controllers. Below is the one for offercontroller.

```
var app = angular.module('ProductCatalog.controllers', []);
app.controller('OfferCtrlr', function ($scope, $http, $modal) {
 });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the arent the same module angular.module('ProductCatalog.controllers', []); this is controller , angular.module('ProductCatalog', ['ui.router']); this is module, must be the same.